# Does apache have to be installed before php or mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, installation

I'm using XAMPP for a while and now I'm trying to install Apache, PHP and MySQL separately.

Should we actually install apache before installing PHP and MySQL?

Comment: For some installation PHP requires the location of httpd, Apache configuration file so the php.ini could be set correctly. but you can install PHP and manually add the necessary settings but I wouldn't recommend that

Answer (score 4):

You can install PHP on the CLI without having Apache installed, but if you want to add PHP support to Apache you have to have it installed first.

You can install MySQL before or after the Apache installation.

Answer (score 3):

PHP can be installed independently but it then has to be connected to the apache installation through the configuration files.

Mysql is completely independent of the other two ... it can be on another machine, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so.

Here is a tutorial : [link](http://connectwww.com/how-to-install-and-configure-apachephpmysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-windows/457/)

Answer (score 1):

You can install them in what ever order you wish as they are stand alone separate applications.
Once you have bought PHP and Apache you just need to integrate PHP in Apache by adding a few lines in it's config as instructed in the PHP installation instructions.